# When device screen off then how to handle firebase notification?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I will try to handle firebase notification when device screen off means wake up the device when a notification arrives. In my project notification divide into so may state so how I can wake up device programmatically whenever required. May also use wake lock, but when screen off then actually

```
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {
    }
```

This method not called so in this circumstances so how I can wake up the device? Can any buddy help me with this issue?

Comment: check my answer and told your web service developer to send notification like that